# Accessing the JSON data from the method in android

Tags: java, android, json, xml

Example of class that will hold the properties in JSONObject and then return the object properties

```
class OperatorProperties {

 JSONObject TigoProperties()
    {
        JSONObject property = new JSONObject();

        try {
            property.put("color", "#223f99");
            property.put("logo", R.drawable.tigo);
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return property;
    }
 }
```

Problems, I don't know how to get the properties details from the JSONObejct

```
JSONObject d = OperatorProperties.TigoProperties();
operatorLogo.setImageResource(d);
```

Any help please because am just want every property should come from the JSONObject

Comment: Make the method ``TigoProperties`` static.

Comment: Drawables are encoded in Base64 in JSON.

Comment: @f1sh after that how can I access the properties when those data needed Broh